# Al ejecutar código en Visual Studio con C# baja la calidad de imagen

Tags: visual-studio

tengo un problema al momento de ejecutar el código en Visual Studio. La calidad no es la misma que se ve al momento de armar el formulario, es decir, las palabras en los labels se ven borrosas, los botones también, etc.

[image: Diseño original]

[image: Programa borroso]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! asi como esta, la pregunta es incontestable.. falta mucha informacion, como por ejemplo si cambias algo a la hora de ejecutar, si hay procesos que impiden que el formulario se pinte como corresponde, si te pasa en todos los proyectos...

Comment: @gbianchi disculpa por las faltas. Cuando desarrollo la parte visual del formulario, este se ve correctamente. Al momento de ejecutarlo para probarlo, funciona correctamente, pero se ve borrosa la calidad. Es más complicado leerlo y queda más feo. Al momento de ejecutarlo no cambio nada, solamente toco el botón que dice "iniciar".

Comment: @gbianchi me pasa en todos los proyectos. Gracias

Comment: Saludos. Sería bueno incluyas capturas de pantalla; no sea el tipo de fuente/tipografia que estes usando; yo uso la predefinida y sin observar tal comportamiento (al menos a como lo entendi en la redacción).

Comment: probaste con otras fuentes? mandar tu proyecto a otra pc? no es un comportamiento conocio... un ejemplo tambien vendria bien...

Comment: Buenas tardes @RobertoLeOr. Recién agregué una captura de pantalla del problema. Esto me pasa con todas las fuentes.

Comment: Hola @gbianchi. Esto me sucede con todas las fuentes. Ahí agregue capturas para que puedas ver las diferencias. Gracias!!

Comment: Tenes aplicado algun modificador de estilo? porque esa ventana no sale igual al ejecutarse.. pareceria eso o que tenes aplicado zoom...

Comment: En las propiedades del formulario está todo por defecto. La única que me aparece en negrita es "AutoScaleMode" que está en "Font". No sé si habrá otra cosa que esté provocando esto. Cómo chequeo lo de los modificadores de estilo? Gracias @gbianchi

Comment: si los tenes, deberias saberlo... y podes probar eso... o cambiar el tamaño del form a ver si eso hace algo tambien...

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @gbianchi . En el foro en inglés me comentaron que cambie la configuración de DPI y pude hacer que funcione correctamente.

Comment: si lo arreglaste, pone una respuesta sobre como lo arreglaste...

Answer (score 0):

La solución del problema fue cambiar el "AutoScaleMode" del formulario a "DPI".
Luego en el "Program.exe" se agregó en la primera instrucción del método principal:

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
SetProcessDPIAware();
```

y una vez cerrado el static void Main:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
```